# Jquery - Ajax: Get-posted "data" inside "error"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Minor question (solution seems simple but i can't seem to find it on google). I would like to use the `data`-setting inside my `error: function`. I know this may sound cryptic but allow me to use an example.

I have the following Ajax-Call (Jquery).

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Search.aspx",
    data: {
        action: 'GetUsers',
        userSearchString: $("#txtUserSearchText").val(),
        Docbase: docbase
    },
    success: function (data) {

        .... (Do something when successfull)

    },
    error: function (xhr, errStatus, thrownError) {

        // RIGHT HERE, i want to use action,userSearchString,Docbase that were passed to Search.aspx 
        // Prefferably i would like to use the data as a whole object and pass it too LogException

        $("#FindUsersModal").modal("hide")
        LogException(errStatus, thrownError, "SearchUsersByInput", params);
    }

})
```

Would anyone care to point me in the right direction?

Thnx for your time.

Answer (score 1):

why not creating the data as an object on the function level and then access it from error callback? for example:

```
function foo(){

    var jsonData = {
            action: 'GetUsers',
            userSearchString: $("#txtUserSearchText").val(),
            Docbase: docbase
        }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Search.aspx",
        data: jsonData,
        success: function (data) {

            .... (Do something when successfull)

        },
        error: function (xhr, errStatus, thrownError) {

            // RIGHT HERE, i want to use action,userSearchString,Docbase that were passed to Search.aspx 

            var something = jsonData.action;        

            $("#FindUsersModal").modal("hide")
            LogException(errStatus, thrownError, "SearchUsersByInput", params);
        }

    })

}
```

Comment: Came across my mind aswell, should be quite simple to do. But i was hoping on some jquery/javascript-trick/property that missed somewhere... (+1 though for pointing it out :) )

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is simple, just store your data in a variable outside the scope of the function, and you can use it where ever you want it within the function.

Here is what you need to do

```
var myData = {
        action: 'GetUsers',
        userSearchString: $("#txtUserSearchText").val(),
        Docbase: docbase
    }

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Search.aspx",
    data: myData,
    success: function (data) {

        .... (Do something when successfull)

    },
    error: function (xhr, errStatus, thrownError) {

        console.log(myData);
        //You can perform any action with myData here
    }

})
```